# Are the quiz answers included in Return To Monkey Island?

Tags: return-to-monkey-island

Ahoy there, fancy pants.

On my *Return to Monkey Island* I found a several quiz cards. As I don't remember all previous adventures in detail and looking up the answers feels like cheating, I'm wondering if I'll find the answers during this adventure.

**Can all quiz answers be found in "Return To Monkey Island" itself, or do I have to look them up in the internet?**

*Example question: "When did Ron Gilbert start working at Lucasfilm Games?"*

Comment: Briefly searching the internet, my answer would be _yes and no_.  This is because it looks like a lot of the cards can be answered by simply _playing the game_ while others (such as your example) I doubt there is any mention in game about those details (since it wouldn't really fit into a fictional video game to talk about real life people).  I'm not saying its impossible, just probably not likely.

Comment: @TimmyJim There is also a summary of previous games and a long credits animation. Mostly wondering if information about the development history is hidden in the game somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. I am almost certain that the "real-world" trivia, such as employee history, and the question about the ending of Monkey Island II, require knowledge that cannot be found within the new sequel.

You have to remember that a large intended fraction of this game's audience are **old-school fans** who have followed the franchise since the first game (in 1990) and might possibly be able to answer those questions from memory, without a search engine.

There is one significant Easter egg in the game (I wanted to put it in spoiler tags, but I can't get the markup working) but that doesn't seem to have any informational content.

Comment: Er, thanks Joachim, for putting spoiler tags around my text saying that I don't know how to do a spoiler. (I actually left out the spoiler content, because I didn't know how to hide it.)

Comment: Then why did you remove the spoiler tags, instead of just adding the content you had left out earlier inside them?